# Finding the general solution to a system of differential equations using eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following system of differential equations:\begin{align*} \begin{cases} x_1'=3x_1+x_2 \\ x_2'=2x_1+x_2 \end{cases} \end{align*}

Putting into standard form:
$$\vec x'= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3&1\\
2&1
    \end{bmatrix}\vec x
$$The eigenvalues are $\lambda=2\pm{\sqrt3}$

And thus the associated eigenvectors are:

$$ 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{{-1-\sqrt3}}{2}\\
1
    \end{bmatrix}
,
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{{\sqrt3}-1}{2}\\
1
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Would this, then, be the correct general form?
$$\vec x=c_1\begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{{-1-\sqrt3}}{2}\\
1
    \end{bmatrix}e^{(2+{\sqrt3})t}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{{\sqrt3}-1}{2}\\
1
    \end{bmatrix}e^{(2-{\sqrt3})t}$$

Comment: Yes, if you insert the $t$ in the exponential (and if your calculations are correct).

Comment: you forgot $t$ in your exponent in the last equation